# Restangular in service

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have service:

```
angular.module('app1App')
  .service('Fullcontactservice', function Fullcontactservice(Restangular, $http, $q) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    var self = this;

    self.apiKey = "..........."

    self.route = "person"

    self.getProfile = function(email){
        console.log("called")
        console.log(email)




        Restangular.one("person").get({email: email, apiKey: self.apiKey})
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response)

            return response
        })


    }
    return self;

  });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app1App')
  .controller('FullcontactCtrl', function ($scope, Fullcontactservice) {


    $scope.searchFullcontact = function(){

        $scope.data = Fullcontactservice.getProfile($scope.email)
    }


  });
```

When I call the searchFullcontact(), Restangular calls fullcontact and returns data but that's not pushed to the scope - I understand why. When I use promises, just results to a `{}` and no data is pushed.

How can I have it do that. I am trying to avoid the `.then()` function within my controller to keep it being slim because traditionally I had very large controllers.

Thanks!

Comment: `getProfile()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: In getProfile, return your call to Restangular.one(....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restangular has a handy feature allowing you to make this code work:

```
self.getProfile = function(email){
    return Restangular.one("person").get({email: email, apiKey: self.apiKey}).$object
}
```

`$object` is effectively a shortcut where Restangular first creates an empty object which is filled with the data from the REST call once it is available. The code working with `$scope.data` inside your controller must be flexible to handle the initially empty object. This is usually not an issue if you use `data` inside the template (html) as angular gracefully handles missing (undefined).